# Why aren't the files in data/data/packagename being deleted when my app is uninstalled?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to fix a bug but this issue is blocking me. I have a file called "scenes.sql" in my data/data/packagename/files folder and even though I click "CLEAR DATA" and "UNINSTALL" in my settings on the test device, the file is still there when I start debugging again.

I've searched my computer's filesystem and deleted every instance of it. I've made sure the "Back up my data" option on the device is false. After clearing and uninstalling, the file gets put in my filesystem again and its creation time is the debug start time. I've set "Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys" to false in visual studio. The assetmanager shows no sign of the file. Is there some other caching mechanism I'm overlooking?

Comment: have you manually deleted your bin and obj folders?

Comment: @Jason I have deleted this file from the bin folder. I've also cleaned and rebuilt.

Comment: @Jason I just tried manually deleting the obj folder and that failed too.

Comment: When you uninstall your app the whole data/data/packagename/ will be deleted. Are you sure you did not change the "packagename"?

Comment: @MikeMa I did about six months back, but since I can access the file using       var x = File.Exists(@"/data/data/Capture.Capture/files/scenes.sql"); and I cannot access the previous package name's folders I assume this means I have the correct folder location. My manifest has app name as "Capture" and
package name as "Capture.Capture"

Comment: So strange, Your app may did some unknown things. Can you crate a new project and move the "scenes.sql" to the /packagename/files foloder and uninstall the app check the “scenes.sql” if it still there.

Comment: @MikeMa I don't think I can. If I uninstall the app, then there will be no app on the device with permission to access that folder to check. I'm starting to think maybe xamarin/visual studio isn't honouring my choice to not preserve app data between deploys

Comment: @Slepz you can use ddms file explorer for checking the file.

Comment: I've found the issue. Visual studio has been ignoring my setting "Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys" and always preserving.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete all app files from pc**

Make a textfile with this code and save it as DeleteBinObj.sh.

```
find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" | xargs rm -rf
```

Go to the folder of your project where you place this script and do in the terminal: `sh DeleteBinObj.sh`

**Delete all app files from Phone**

Make a textfile with this code and save it as Uninstall.sh.
Go to the folder of this script in the terminal and do: `sh Uninstall.sh YOURNAMESPACE`

Now your namespacefolder including saved appfiles and database will be deleted.

```
  echo "Going to platform tools $HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
  cd $HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
  echo "uninstalling app with packagae name $1"
  ./adb uninstall $1
```